# Removing newline from AddMessage() with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, newline

I am looking for a way to add text in the same line in the progress dialog box.
The **AddMessage()** adds a **newline** and this is not convenient.

For example:
I want to have one line with the text:

```
arcpy.AddMessage("Sorting data...Done")
```

where "Sorting data..." should appear before the execution of the tool and "Done" after it.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: are you able to create an example - a mockup and post it?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this can be done, and have never come across a requirement for it.

My only thought was to try a backspace (\b) so I tried the code below behind a Python script tool:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.AddMessage("Doing something ...")

arcpy.AddMessage ("\bDone")
```

When I ran it this is what appeared in the tool results dialog:

[image]

Comment: I see. Maybe I should give up this effort. It would be nice though to have such an option! :-)

Comment: @Panos It's not one that I would vote for (without more convincing of a need for it), but you could post it to ArcGIS Ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use something like this below (if I understand your question correctly)

```
import arcpy

arcpy.AddMessage("Sorting data")

# code to sort data...

arcpy.AddMessage("Done")
```

This is an example from code I have used previously:

```
arcpy.AddMessage(".....Sorting chainages based on distance")

arcpy.Sort_management(Chainage_FC_Tempv2,chainage_FeatureClass, [["POINT_M", "ASCENDING"]])

arcpy.AddMessage("........Finished sorting chainages")
```

Comment: @TsvGisThanks for the immediate reply. As I said on my question at the end of execution of the tool i want the text to be only in one line. Your example gives a 2 lines text! :-)

Comment: Sorry, I think I got confused with this line _"where "Sorting data..." should appear before the execution of the tool and "Done" after it"_